# React-native npm install fatal error: 'CoreServices/CoreServices.h' file not found

Tags: react-native

When I run "npm install" on my react-native project, I get errors when I don't run with sudo.  Note, I get the same problem when I run the Facebook starter project "react-native init AwesomeProject".

This problem is new and so far I've tried:

```
- re-installing xcode v7.3.1 (7D1014)
- re-installing node-v6.2.0 (npm v3.8.9)
- downgrading to node-v6.1.0 (npm v3.8.6)
- removing node version manager (nvm)
```

The net effect is that npm doesn't install fsevents@1.0.12.

```
├─┬ react-native@0.24.0 
│ ├─┬ fbjs-scripts@0.4.0 
│ │ ├─┬ babel@5.8.38 
│ │ │ ├─┬ chokidar@1.5.1 
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ fsevents@1.0.12
```

**With Sudo:**

> npm WARN deprecated MD5@1.2.2: deprecated, use lowercase 'md5@2.x'
>   from now on npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn
>   no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead! npm WARN
>   deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package has been discontinued in
>   favor of lodash@^4.0.0. npm WARN lifecycle
>   typechecker@2.0.8~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s)
>   typechecker@2.0.8 node ./cyclic.js
>   /Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/.staging/typechecker-7c919859
>   npm WARN prefer global cover@0.2.9 should be installed with -g npm
>   WARN prefer global babel@5.8.38 should be installed with -g
>
> > fsevents@1.0.12 install /Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/fsevents
> >     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node   CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o   SOLINK_MODULE(target)
>   Release/fse.node   COPY
>   /Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64/fse.node
>   TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
>
> > bufferutil@1.2.1 install /Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/bufferutil
> >     node-gyp rebuild
>
> CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
>   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
>
> > utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> >     node-gyp rebuild
>
> CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
>   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
>
> > spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall /Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/spawn-sync
> >     node postinstall

**Without Sudo:**

> npm WARN deprecated MD5@1.2.2: deprecated, use lowercase 'md5@2.x'
>   from now on npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn
>   no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead! npm WARN
>   deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package has been discontinued in
>   favor of lodash@^4.0.0.
>
> > typechecker@2.0.8 preinstall /Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/.staging/typechecker-7c919859
> >     node ./cyclic.js
>
> npm WARN prefer global cover@0.2.9 should be installed with -g npm
>   WARN prefer global babel@5.8.38 should be installed with -g
>
> > fsevents@1.0.12 install /Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/fsevents
> >     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> 2016-05-24 10:36:25.735 xcodebuild[37842:5261935] Build settings from
>   command line: 2016-05-24 10:36:25.736 xcodebuild[37842:5261935]
>   TOOLCHAINS = com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault 2016-05-24
>   10:36:25.736 xcodebuild[37842:5261935]
>   XCODE_DEFAULT_TOOLCHAIN_OVERRIDE =
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
>   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node ld: warning: URGENT: building for
>   OSX, but linking against dylib
>   (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib)
>   built for iOS. Note: This will be an error in the future. ld: warning:
>   URGENT: building for OSX, but linking against dylib
>   (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib)
>   built for iOS. Note: This will be an error in the future.
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o ../fsevents.cc:11:10:
>   fatal error: 'CoreServices/CoreServices.h' file not found
>
> ## include "CoreServices/CoreServices.h"
>
> ```
>      ^ 1 error generated. make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1 gyp ERR! build error  gyp
> ```
>
> ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 gyp ERR! stack
>   at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.5.0 gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "build" "--fallback-to-build"
>   "--module=/Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64/fse.node"
>   "--module_name=fse"
>   "--module_path=/Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64"
>   gyp ERR! cwd /Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/fsevents gyp
>   ERR! node -v v6.1.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1 gyp ERR! not ok 
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! build error  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed
>   to execute '/usr/local/bin/node
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   build --fallback-to-build
>   --module=/Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64/fse.node
>   --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64'
>   (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.
>   (/Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:215:5) node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin
>   15.5.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp"
>   "install" "--fallback-to-build" node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
>   /Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/fsevents node-pre-gyp ERR!
>   node -v v6.1.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.25 node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! not ok  Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
>   build --fallback-to-build
>   --module=/Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64/fse.node
>   --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64'
>   (1) npm WARN install:fsevents@1.0.12 fsevents@1.0.12 install:
>   `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build` npm WARN
>   install:fsevents@1.0.12 Exit status 1
>
> > bufferutil@1.2.1 install /Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/bufferutil
> >     node-gyp rebuild
>
> 2016-05-24 10:36:38.662 xcodebuild[37889:5262508] Build settings from
>   command line: 2016-05-24 10:36:38.663 xcodebuild[37889:5262508]
>   TOOLCHAINS = com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault 2016-05-24
>   10:36:38.663 xcodebuild[37889:5262508]
>   XCODE_DEFAULT_TOOLCHAIN_OVERRIDE =
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
>   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node ld: warning: URGENT:
>   building for OSX, but linking against dylib
>   (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib)
>   built for iOS. Note: This will be an error in the future. ld: warning:
>   URGENT: building for OSX, but linking against dylib
>   (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib)
>   built for iOS. Note: This will be an error in the future.
>
> > utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> >     node-gyp rebuild
>
> 2016-05-24 10:36:42.522 xcodebuild[37965:5262650] Build settings from
>   command line: 2016-05-24 10:36:42.523 xcodebuild[37965:5262650]
>   TOOLCHAINS = com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault 2016-05-24
>   10:36:42.523 xcodebuild[37965:5262650]
>   XCODE_DEFAULT_TOOLCHAIN_OVERRIDE =
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
>   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
>   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node ld: warning: URGENT:
>   building for OSX, but linking against dylib
>   (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib)
>   built for iOS. Note: This will be an error in the future. ld: warning:
>   URGENT: building for OSX, but linking against dylib
>   (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib)
>   built for iOS. Note: This will be an error in the future.
>
> > spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall /Users/andreahylton/idpractice/node_modules/spawn-sync
> >     node postinstall

Comment: any updates on this ?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I'm still stuck with using sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting my ~/.node-gyp and ~/.npmrc and then restarting my mac, check out this thread https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809